# Issue adding 3rd party module in Angular2 project

Tags: angular

I've created a project using `ng-cli` and I'm trying to include a 3rd party module according to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs) wiki:

**I've included path to `angular-cli-build.js`**
now it looks like:

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');
module.exports = function(defaults) {
    return new Angular2App(defaults, {
        vendorNpmFiles: [
           ...
            'my3rdParty/**/*.+(ts|ts.map)'
        ]
    });
};
```

**And in `system-config.js`:**

```
const map: any = {
  'my3rdParty': 'vendor/my3rdParty/my3rdParty.ts'
};
const packages: any = {};
```

Here creates a const array named barrels and an object named `cliSystemConfigPackages` of type `any` then uses them:

```
// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
 System.config({
      map: {
          '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
          'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
          'main': 'main.js'
      },
      packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
  });

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

And I see the module is copies into `dist/vendor` directory.

**I'm importing it:**

```
import { myModule } from 'my3rdParty';
```

and the error I get is:

> Error: Typescript found the following errors:
>
> .../0/src/components/app/app.component.ts (6, 34): Cannot find module 'my3rdParty'.

Comment: Can you confirm that User packages configuration for `my3rdParty` module is included `config = {  map: map,   packages: packages  }` in `system-config.js` ?

Comment: Possibly, you are missing out package configuration. It should be `const packages: any = { 'my3rdParty': {defaultExtension: 'js', main:'index.js'}  }` For more details check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs)

Comment: @KunalSharma I've just added this config, unfortunatly still the same error

Comment: Follow this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs) This will certainly help you out. You are surely missing configuration for your 3rd party module here `const packages: any = {}`.